# Trying to get the name of a cluster in WLST

Tags: python, wlst

Im trying to get the string value name of the first cluster of a datasource in wlst

```
cd("/JDBCSystemResources/<datasource name>")
targets = get('Targets')
mytarget = targets[0]
```

This works fine. If I use a viewMBean command "viewMBean(mytarget)" I can see the Name as the attribute "Name"

If I print the value mytarget I get something like: "com.bea:Name=Cluster-1,Type=Cluster"

But I cannot work out how to get the name ("Cluster-1" in the example above)

At the moment I can't think of anything to do other than getting the cluster name as a substring of the string representation of the object, which doesn't sound like the thing to do

Any help appreciated.

Update:

With no answers so far I'm using this solution, but still hoping for a better one

```
# get the target cluster from the string "com.bea:Name=<clustername>,Type=Cluster"
if len(targets) == 1 :
    tstring = str(targets[0])
    targetCluster = tstring[13:tstring.find(",Type=Cluster")]
    print "targetCluster = "+targetCluster;
else :
    raise Exception("Expected single target cluster for datasource. Targets length was "+str(len(targets)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just say `targets[0].getName()` worked for me :)

Comment: Better late than never ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Code in the question seems to be the best answer for this. Ie Convert the cluster to a string and then sub-string that to get the cluster name.